# Register Script PHP MySQL Not Inserting into DB

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am stumped as to why this code will not work.  I am trying to insert data into a MySQL Database called 'clubresults' with a table called 'members'.  Usually this kind of stuff is fairly easy for me however nothing is showing up in the database. Obviously just running this off localhost for now using xammpp.  Code Below.

Config.php

```
<?php 
 // Connects to your Database 

 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 

 mysql_select_db("clubresults") or die(mysql_error());


?>
```

RegProcess.php - Main PHP Class

```
<?php 
include "config.php";

$Firstname = $_POST['Firstname'];
$Surname = $_POST['Surname'];
$Password = md5($_POST['Password']);
$Email = $_POST['Email'];


$insert = 'INSERT into members(Firstname, Surname, Password, Email) VALUES ("'.$Firstname.'", "'.$Surname.'", "'.Password.'", "'.$Email.'")';
mysql_query($insert);

?>
```

Register.php - Includes HTML Form

```
        <form action="regprocess.php" method="post">
             <table border="0">
             <tr><td colspan=2><h1>Register</h1></td></tr> <br>
             <tr><td>Firstname:</td><td>
             <input type="text" name="Firstname" maxlength="60">
             </td></tr>
             <tr><td>Surname:</td><td>
             <input type="text" name="Surname" maxlength="60">
             </td></tr>
             <tr><td>Password:</td><td>
             <input type="password" name="Password" maxlength="20">
             </td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td>
             <input type="text" name="Email" maxlength="50">
             </td></tr>
             <tr><th colspan=2><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"> 
         </form>
```

Comment: You have password as plain word there in insert statement you should be getting mysql errors in this statement.

Comment: doing this will show you what the error is, if it is an sql error mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: okay now it is producing the code which is in regproccess.php and not actually processing it. thanks for all your help guys btw

Answer (score 1):

```
$insert = 'INSERT into members(Firstname, Surname, Password, Email) VALUES ("'.$Firstname.'", "'.$Surname.'", "'.$Password.'", "'.$Email.'")';
                                                                                                                    ^^
```

u forgot putting `$` before `password`

Comment: Hi guys, I have fixed these error and I am still getting nothing in the SQL Database.

Comment: try echoing the query statement and varibales, and try to excute the query in console, and look for the error(if any) u getting

Comment: Hi i have added echo like this - echo mysql_query($insert); and nothing is displayed when the browser reaches regprocess.php

Comment: try echo $insert; before excecuting mysql_query

Comment: still gives nothing being echoed.

Comment: okay now it is producing the code which is in regproccess.php and not actually processing it. thanks for all your help guys btw

Comment: put some random echo statement like echo "hi"; in RegProcess.php, and look for the result , i doubt about  pointing someother file in form action check for that also, try by changing form action with RegProcess.php

<form action="RegProcess.php" method="post">

Comment: nope not seeing the echo only seeing the actual code which is inside regprocess.php including the <?php tags